# Identityserver3 error Unable to get document from: https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver3

I have created an identityserver to issue token. Using identityserver3 to setup.
I am using a local .pfx certificate with password for signing the tokens.

this was working good but not sure why i am getting the following error as shown in the attachment.

Really making me crazy.

Below is the code in startup.cs on the authorization server. The certificate file is located in \bin\debug folder

```
public class X509Certificate2Wrapper : IX509Certificate2Wrapper
{
    public X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(string filename, string password)
    {
        var path = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}{filename}";

        return new X509Certificate2(path, password);
    }
}

    app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
    {
        idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Identity Manager",
            IssuerUri = Common.Constants.IdSrvIssuerUri,
            SigningCertificate = X509Certificate2Wrapper.LoadCertificate(CertificateFilename, CertificatePassword),
            Factory = factory,
            RequireSsl = true,
            EnableWelcomePage = false,
            AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
            {
                EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
                EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay = 3,
                CookieOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.CookieOptions
                {
                    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, IdentityServerServices.AuthenticationTimeout(), 0),
                    SlidingExpiration = true
                },
                //
                // Note: Uncomment following line to enable WindowsAuthentication only - logout related settings will also require removal!
                //
                //EnableLocalLogin = false,
                IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
            },
            Endpoints = new EndpointOptions
            {
                EnableAccessTokenValidationEndpoint = true,
                EnableAuthorizeEndpoint = true,
                EnableCheckSessionEndpoint = false,
                EnableClientPermissionsEndpoint = false,
                EnableCspReportEndpoint = false,
                EnableDiscoveryEndpoint = true,
                EnableEndSessionEndpoint = true,
                EnableIdentityTokenValidationEndpoint = true,
                EnableIntrospectionEndpoint = false,
                EnableTokenEndpoint = true,
                EnableTokenRevocationEndpoint = false,
                EnableUserInfoEndpoint = true
            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the perfect answer. But i did the following and all working fine for me.

i) followed steps regarding certificatesas mentioned in https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Certificates

ii) To resolve this I moved the "localhost" IIS Express Cert from the Personal CertStore to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities and the issue was gone.